# Why is the Container not restricting the height of the ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've created a ListView that contains a larger number of Rows.  The idea is that the entire list will not be displayed and the user can scroll through them.  The thing is, when I put the ListView inside of a Container with a specified height, it ignores the height of the container.  Here is my code:

```
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: list
      ),
    );
```

The thing is, when I wrap the Container with a Center widget, the height of the ListView restricts to 150:

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 150,
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: list
    ),
  ),
);
```

I'm sure I'm just mis-understanding something with regard to how Flutter renders, can anyone explain what that is?

Comment: Not sure this can happen. Can you post the entire code of your page ?

Comment: I used the exact code and rendered 4 children with 50 height each, seems to work fine. Can you post your full code?

Comment: the parent of the container is responsible for the behavior. Please be mentioned, column/expanded widget by default occupies full empty space, and its a child is forced to occupy the full space it has.

Comment: what @GourangoSutradhar said is absolutely right. Provide the parent of the Container for further looking into this. Container height constraints will be ignored if the parent is Row (with crossAxisAlignment as stretch), Expanded, etc. I suggest you have a look at the following [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I think ListView can't scroll back to the container. If listView's height is more than the screen size, you can't scroll back to the container
you can use `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 150,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
       children: [
        // TODO
      ],
     ), 
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi, ListView will restrict to parent container. Do you suggest that listView does not respect container constraints. If so, please do review your answer. [reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial)